# Unable to get Google Arms Globe working after updating data through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have recently downloaded [Googles armsglobe chromeexperiment](http://armsglobe.chromeexperiments.com/) and used it for showing country datas on the globe. but i wanted to refresh the data every 5mins. here is how i tried to update the data:

```html
// ensure the map images are loaded first!!
mapIndexedImage = new Image();
mapIndexedImage.src = 'images/map_indexed.png';
mapIndexedImage.onload = function() {
    mapOutlineImage = new Image();
    mapOutlineImage.src = 'images/map_outline.png';
    mapOutlineImage.onload = function(){
     loadCountryCodes(
      function(){
       loadWorldPins(
        function(){          
         loadContentData(        
          function(){                 
           initScene();
           animate();  
          }
         );              
        }
       );
      }
     );
    };   
}; 
//setInterval(mapIndexedImage.onload, 300000);
```

The ^ last commented line was my only code. it works and gets the data; `loadContentData()` gets the data from server(db) and the two functions inside draws and `animate()` the globe according to the data provided. but whenever a new data is received the globe crashes and doesn't move. is there any better way to implement this without crashing the globe?

Thanks for your help!!! Really appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, 5 minutes is 300000 in milliseconds.

Comment: My bad, forgot to change it after testing it with lower time.

Comment: It's likely that you need to gracefully unload the globe before it is reanimated. Otherwise you need to create a different function to "update" rather than load the globe every 5 minutes.

Comment: oh, makes sense. but how can i technically unload the globe before it is reanimated? The worst part is, the globe needs to be updated along with the data, since the globe differs as the data. i have tried to put `setInterval()` before(wrapped) `loadContentData()` function but that doesnt even get the new data.

Comment: Any chance you could make a jsfiddle with it working that I could mess with?

Comment: I would love to, but it has a lot of dependencies(js files) that might be hard for it to work. but i can make one of the important file that you can mess with, and is definitely the only file that does almost all the work.